# Database connection from MFC application

Tags: database, visual-c++, mfc

I am a complete beginner in MFC. Just for practice I have created a dialog-box which consist of a combo box, 2 editboxes and a button. Now I want to connect to database when I click the button from my dialog-box so that the data that is entered in the combo box and editboxes will be stored in a database table. Can anyone tell how to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with ? The database connection, the SQL, or the MFC code (how to fetch values from `CComboBox` / `CEdit` / etc.) ? Post some code of your attempt(s) please.

Comment: The MFC code to connect to the database. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several classes in MFC to work with database including `CDatabase` and `CRecordset`. So called **Data Source Name (DSN)** is used to access the database. Here is the sample code that stores data to **ODBC**-compliant DB:

```
  CString sID;
  m_EditBox.GetWindowText(sID);
  int nID = _ttoi(sID);

  CString sName;
  m_ComboBox.GetWindowText(sName);

  CDatabase db;

  try
  {
     db.OpenEx(_T("DSN=MYDSN"), CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
     CString sSQL;
     sSQL.Format(_T("insert into mytable (ID, NAME) values(%d, '%s')"), nID, sName); 
     db.ExecuteSQL(sSQL);
  }
  catch(CDBException* pEx)
  {
     pEx->ReportError();
     pEx->Delete();
  }
  db.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Komiagin.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark it as an answer if the answer suits you.

Comment: Isn't there any prerequisites ? How to connect to ODBC before coding? This might be silly, but I'm a newbie...

Comment: You have to configure ODBC Datasource via Control Panel->Admin Tools->ODBC before you can use it. Make sure you have proper ODBC driver for your database.